# VHDL Simple code optimization

Tags: arrays, loops, optimization, vhdl, fpga

Here is my code :

```
             variable input: array(0 to 3, 0 to 3) of unsigned(7 downto 0);
             variable outt: array(0 to 3, 0 to 175) of unsigned(7 downto 0);
           for i in 0 to 3 loop
              outt(0,i) :=input(0,i);
     outt(1,i) :=input(1,i);
     outt(2,i) :=input(2,i);
      outt(3,i) :=input(3,i);

      end loop;
```

Is there a better way to do this?I mean an efficient code to copy all of input array in a part of the larger outt array ?

Comment: Is it rather a compact notation you are looking for? Optimization doesn't really apply to VHDL. Two nested loops could be a bit more compact.

Comment: I just want to make it more efficient to reduce hardware needed but if it wont matter then i dont have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb for loops in VHDL are unrolled, as the purpose of a loop is to synthesize multiple copies of hardware described in the loop body. The control logic does not appear in the synthesized hardware.

For that reason, a more compact way to write multiple assignments is to do two nested loops.

```
 for i in 0 to 3 loop
  for j in 0 to 3 loop
    out(i,j) := in(i,j);  // there will be 16 wires / flipflops synthesized
  end loop;
 end loop;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
outt(0 to 3, 0 to 3) := input;
```

Comment: didnt work :
parse error, unexpected COMMA, expecting CLOSEPAR

Answer (score 0):

For maximum flexibility, you can use nested loops and attributes to cope with changes in the size of `i`:

```
for i in i'range(1) loop
  for j in i'range(2) loop
    outt(i,j) := input(i,j);  
  end loop;
end loop;
```